# Sharing a local server with 'Code with me' in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide, pair-programming

In the **JetBrains**` page for **Code With Me**, I can see a paragraph mentioning:

> You can use Code With Me for real time collaboration, editing code, sharing a server, and running a debugging session.

However, I cannot see how a server can be shared. For example, if I start API server locally, I cannot find a way to share it through **Code With Me**.

I am just and only looking for a way of sharing that local server through **Code With Me**, not any third-party website or so.

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to share access to your server running locally with a guest.

For this scenario, there is a **Code With Me** tool-window in the right bottom corner which allows you to forward a port. The tool-window appears when the Code With Me session is active.

Does it fit your needs?